# Is there a way to convert IPv6-style IPv4 addresses in X-Forwarded-For headers to IPv4-style?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, ipv6, pound

I run a system that has a Pound reverse proxy in front of a squid accelerator, in turn in front of Apache2 powering a few PHP-based webapps.

The Pound daemon is configured to send X-Forwarded-For headers to Apache so the aforementioned applications can determine the true source of a message (squid is configured to transparently pass on the X-Forwarded-For headers without modification).  However, Pound notates IPv4 addresses in XFF headers like `::ffff:1.2.3.4` instead of simply as `1.2.3.4`, and this throws off the applications.

Aside from modifying each application to correctly handle the `::ffff:1.2.3.4` case, is there a way to either stop Pound from using the IPv6 notation or in Apache to preemptively convert the IPv6 notation back to IPv4 notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) to rewrite the `X-Forwarded-For` header prior to the php applications seeing it:

```
RequestHeader edit X-Forwarded-For "^::ffff:" ""
```